# my site is very laggy on ipad/iphone, removed css-effects & javascript

Tags: iphone, html, performance, ipad, sticky

I'm building a site with quite a bit of CSS & some javascript but I am having a lot of problems with the performance on mobile devices, especially on the ipad and the iphone.

I've tried turning off the box-shadow, text-shadow, radius and gradient properties in css as well as turning off all the javascript but it's still lagging severely. Turning off the javascript doesn't improve the performance much, though turning off those css properties did help a bit.

More specifically, when you try scrolling and let go with your finger the scrolling "sticks" on the spot where you let go. Zooming in and scrolling around is pretty bad on smaller screens as well, especially on the iphone or ipod.

It does feel like there are things I am overlooking. Any clues?

*[I removed the site, but my answer shows the underlying problem in more detail. The sluggish behavior comes from the property overflow:scroll]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
overflow : scroll;
```

was my problem...

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

adding this line made scrolling smooth.

Initially I thought it was an issue with multiple divs stacked on top of each other but then I researched it more thoroughly and found this site which explains iOS touch behavior in more detail:
http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/

way simpler of a solution than I thought.

**edit:**
not so fast, now I have display issues with some elements. Researched it again and found this: http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/

which tells me to use

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

on all relative elements.
That kind of worked when I used it on some of my elements, but again it broke something else. Now when I scroll down, the page takes about 3 seconds! to load content that was previously not visible...

I guess it's better than nothing, though it almost feels like Mobile Safari is the new Internet Explorer
Will try to find another fix...

**edit2:**
I managed to get it mostly working. It still has some display issues (the main background behing my elements still has the 2-3sec loading problem) but at least my other elements are instantly visible.

What I did is use

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

on one of my top-most (id #) elements, instead of all the relative elements as mentioned in the article with the universal selector *{}

For backwards compatibility with the scrolling behavior they mention a polyfill such as [overthrow](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/).

Comment: actually, this "trick" creates problems. my javascript-related css is now all messed up...

Comment: using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` on all relative elements kind of helps in fixing the weird behaviour, updated my answer

Comment: Have you tried applying the `-webkit-backface-visibility` property on a high level element with elements of either `visible` or `hidden`? This can have a similar effect to `transform: translate3d` in that it can force GPU acceleration – with different weird side-effects ;)

Answer (score 2):

Run a YSlow! test. It gives me some interesting points...

```
This page has 10 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
This page has 5 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I didn't know about YSlow.
Yet, the initial page-load is not what I'm concerned about. It is the laggy behaviour while you're on the site.